# AR complex CAD model tracking

Tags: android, opencv, augmented-reality, cad, metaio

I need some help with 3D-CAD model tracking.

I have to develop an android application that tracks predefined CAD models like parts of a car, e.g. you stand in front of the car with the engine hood opened and the application should tell you what you have to do now (perhabs refill some fluid) with visual support like arrows or cicles. The following youtube video describes my intention https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4LE_IocFnL0

I have tried this with the Metaio SDK but when I try to transform the CAD models with the MetaioCreator to edge and surface models you cannot recognize any part of the model. I think this is because my models are very detailed (~400.000 polygons each). In addition for test purpose I reduced the polygons to a much lower count (~7.000 polygons), but when I create the edge and surface model an load this models in my test application my test device (Samsung Galaxy Tab S) laggs extremly and its not possible to track the model.

So I would like to ask you if this is the right way because I don't think so.. Perhaps you could give me an advice which tracking method I should get use of.

So far I used the MetaioSDK hybrid 3D tracking witch is a mix from an edgebased and an featurebased trackingmethod. Is there annother method witch is better to reach my goal? I've read about the openCV (witch is available for android too) but i dont now if this is a good method for 3d CAD tracking. Has anyone experience in this kind of augmented reality?

I have the following requirements:
- the framework / toolkit must be running on android
- the tracking should be independent from changing light ratio
- I have to track many different CAD models (the user select one wich shoud now be tracked)
- the user selected CAD model can be more than once in the current viewport and every single must selectable for further rendering operations
- the performance must be well when its running on an wearable device

In addition when there is a group of switches which shall be tracked, is there a possibility to track when the user pressed the marked switch? When I know the exact relative position from all my CAD models is there a possibility to join them together? My intent is that a user tracks model A and by selecting another trackable the device knows the approximately position based on the position from model A and the relative position difference to the new model.

Hope for responses,
lost1994

PS: If something is ambiguous or I didn't explain it cleary please don't be afraid of asking.

Answer (score 0):

I know my answer is maybe a bit late, but anyway:
In general 3d-edge-based tracking is a good choice here. You are using the hybrid version which is good if your AR world wont change (means your car stays on a static position and wont be moved).
The reason for your laggs is that you still have 7000 polygons. That's to much for mobile. Reduce it to 3000 or less (3000 is fine on iPhone6).

Note: Metaio has closed the doors (they have been bought by Apple).